# How to work with localization/translations in Firefox OS/b2g

Tags: firefox, localization, translation, firefox-os, b2g

There seem to be a lot of variations of how the workflow for localization should be. When I look at the documentation I find differences on all of the pages:

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/Apps/Build/Localization/Localizing_Firefox_OS_Apps

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/Apps/Build/Localization/Getting_started_with_app_localization

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/Apps/Build/Localization/Localizing_strings_in_JavaScript

https://github.com/robnyman/TranslationTester

https://github.com/robnyman/Firefox-OS-Boilerplate-App

I have tried all versions and combinations that I can think of (my phone is a Geeksphone Revolution running Firefox OS 2.0) but nothing works as intended. Either I get no text at all or I always get English.

To name one of the uncertainties, how should the localization link-tag look like. So far I have tried these variations (each with corresponding file structure for .ini/.properties files):

```
<link rel="prefetch" type="application/l10n" href="locales/locales.ini">
<link rel="resource" type="application/l10n" href="locales/locales.ini">
<link rel="localization" href="locales/{locale}/app.properties">
<link rel="prefetch" href="locales/{locale}/app.properties">
```

Since all documentation pages on developer.mozilla.org and the GitHub pages they link to looks different, how can I find out which is the standard way to work with localization for Firefox OS/b2g 2.x?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe this link:
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/Apps/Build/Localization/Localizing_Firefox_OS_Apps
reflects the latest changes in the l10n.js lib in Gaia.

The other methods can be used as long as you have the js file that supports it.

For example The translation tester app should work. I just tried it on 2.0 on a Flame and it worked fine.
Using

```
<link rel="resource" type="application/l10n" href="locales/locales.ini" />
```

Should work.
Look over this post:
https://hacks.mozilla.org/2014/05/introducing-translationtester-and-localization-support-for-open-web-apps/
That Robert used with that example and uses a locales.ini file in the locales directory.
Also check to see if your app is working in the 2.0 simulator.

Comment: Thanks, yes I figured out that the key was using the correct version of the l10n.js file. I ended up using the link tag that you mentioned and https://raw.githubusercontent.com/robnyman/TranslationTester/gh-pages/js/l10n.js which is probably an older version since the API is document.webL10n, but it works finally so this will be good enough for now.

As a reference others that has this problem can look at my project at https://github.com/tirithen/kodi-remote .

Comment: I hope that the localization API and documentation stabilizes soon.